# Excel VBA to for inputbox to select sheets to forma

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code below that needs to be tweaked, as I want to be able to enter my sheet name in an input box and have it reformat the sheet and output next to the sheet I select.

See formula I attempted but failed.

```
Sub Chart()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim wsRaw As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
   Dim iRow As Byte, iCol As Byte, iResultRow As Byte, iRawCol As Byte
   Dim Result As String

Result = InputBox("Provide a sheet name.")
Workbooks(wb).Sheets(Result).Select
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     Set wsRaw = Application.ActiveSheet
   Set wsResult = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.count))
   iRow = 2

 iResultRow = 2

  Do Until wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1) = Empty

  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 1) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 1) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 1) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1)

  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 2) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 2)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 2) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 2)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 2) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 2)

  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 3) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 3)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 3) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 3)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 3) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 3)

  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 4) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 4)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 4) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 4)
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 4) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 4)

  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 5) = "Lender"
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 5) = "All"
  wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 5) = "Percent"

  iRawCol = 5
  iCol = 6
  Do Until iCol = 46
    wsResult.Cells(1, iCol) = Left(wsRaw.Cells(1, iRawCol), 9)
    wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, iCol) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, iRawCol)
    wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, iCol) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, iRawCol + 1)
    wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, iCol) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, iRawCol + 2)
    iCol = iCol + 1
    iRawCol = iRawCol + 3
  Loop
iResultRow = iResultRow + 3
 iRow = iRow + 1
  Loop

    Sheets("Macros").Select
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Chart()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsRaw As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Byte, iCol As Byte, iResultRow As Byte, iRawCol As Byte
Dim Result As Worksheet, RangeResult As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ResultRange = Application.InputBox("Provide a sheet name.", Type:=8)
Set Result = ResultRange.Parent
wb.Result.Select

Set wsRaw = Application.ActiveSheet
Set wsResult = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
iRow = 2

iResultRow = 2

Do Until wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1) = Empty

wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 1) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 1) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 1) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 1)

wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 2) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 2)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 2) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 2)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 2) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 2)

wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 3) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 3)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 3) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 3)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 3) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 3)

wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 4) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 4)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 4) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 4)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 4) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, 4)

wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, 5) = "Lender"
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, 5) = "All"
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, 5) = "Percent"

iRawCol = 5
iCol = 6
Do Until iCol = 46
wsResult.Cells(1, iCol) = Left(wsRaw.Cells(1, iRawCol), 9)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow, iCol) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, iRawCol)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 1, iCol) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, iRawCol + 1)
wsResult.Cells(iResultRow + 2, iCol) = wsRaw.Cells(iRow, iRawCol + 2)
iCol = iCol + 1
iRawCol = iRawCol + 3
Loop
iResultRow = iResultRow + 3
iRow = iRow + 1
Loop

Sheets("Macros").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry could you put it in context to the vba code . I m still learning it and may have broken my code even more .thanks

Comment: Set ResultRange = InputBox("Provide a sheet name.", Type:=8) the statement is returning with a debug message "Compile Error:Named argument not found"

Comment: Okay, I modified your original code.  I changed ws from string to worksheet and moved set wb = thisworkbook to set it before its called.  Let me know if you have any other errors.

Comment: i got to the message input box and when I enter the worksheets name either by typing or clicking on the actual worksheet it returns an error " A formula in this worksheet contain one or more invalid references. verify that your formulas contain a valid path, workbook, range name , and cell reference)" .. thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Since we declared it as a range and since we are using type 8 for the inputbox, we have to provide a range object.  Basically, when they inputbox appears, you should be able to select/activate the sheet you want and then click on an actual cell (you can actually click a range of cells or columns).  This would give the program a range on your destination worksheet.  Then the program will grab the parent sheet and work with that.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks , I tried selecting a certain range from the sheet I want to be reformatted . eg "'Sample'!$A$1:$AZ$17" and return with the following error on this statement "Workbooks(wb).Sheets(Result).Select" with the following error msg "runtime error 13:type mismatch" .. sorry not sure what I am doing wrong .

Comment: okay, I removed the workbooks method when specifying wb.  It was redundant.  See if that works (it would only work if the sheet you're selecting is in the workbook containing the code - hence "thisworkbook").

Comment: Thank, sorry to do this again , but I am doing the same thing selecting the worksheet and the code is definitely in the same workbook . And I return the following error ("runtime error 13:type mismatch")  on the following statement "wb.Sheets(Result).Select"

Comment: Ahhh yes, that would make sense.  We've declared Result as a worksheet (a worksheet object).  Then we've set the result worksheet object.  So just as using Workbooks(wb) is redundant (using a workbooks method on a workbook object), using Sheets() on a worksheet object is also redundant.  I edited the code.  Can you try it and see what you get?

Comment: actually, by deleting "wb.result.select statement disallows me to select the sheet I am after . Just notice the error . So I tried it with the new code you provided and it comes back with the following error message "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" on statement : wb.Result.Select ...

Comment: Okay.  That would be because 'Select' is a method for range objects, not sheets.  How about changing it to:  Result.Activate